# Continuous integration azure slow or fails

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure, azure-devops

Two weeks ago the deployment time for my Azure Bots started to be totally atypical

Before it was running between 2-4 minutes max. but since then it takes more than 30mins or most of the times directly fails and the only output I see is the following:

Log file:
[deploy.log](https://pastebin.com/axHujWam)

```
Thread was being aborted.
Thread was being aborted.
```

that doesn't say that much.

This fails when I configure the continuous deployment option through the portal.azure site. If I disconnect it and set up the autodeploy from the visual studio team services sites it works.

In the activity log I could find this:

> > Operation name Write Deployments
> >
> > Time stamp Thu May 17 2018 14:46:49 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
> >
> > Event initiated by XXXXX@XXXX.XXX
> >
> > Error code ClientClosedRequest
> >
> > Message The connection has been closed by the client while the server is still processing its request for 'Microsoft.Web'.

Any idea about this?

Comment: I agree. Azure CI is very slow. I am thinking of moving to alternative way of deployment to azure using Chef.

Comment: This sounds like a support case for Azure, I don't see how anyone could have the slightest idea on what's going wrong there without working for Azure.

Comment: @Tensibai you are right. I opened a ticket in support, but I thought maybe someone could be aware of the problem and found a setting to tweak the deployment